# uploading files to server php

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I tested my code locally and everything works fine, I tried with 0777 and 0755 permissions on server for the folders and still the upload of a file is not working. My code is:

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  

$storeFolder = '..\uploads';   

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error) { 
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];    //temporary file                  

            $file_name = mt_rand(1000000,9999999); //generate the number for file name

            $imageName = $file_name.'.' . pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'][$key],PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // set the new file name

            $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds; //target path where the image will be stored

            $targetFile =  $targetPath. $imageName;   // set the target path and image, url

            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //move the uploaded file     

            echo 'BCK../uploads/'. $imageName;

        }
    }

}
```

I tried almost everything. And uploading is still not working. This .php script returns response like this:

```
BCK../uploads/5631131.jpg
```

So obviously there is a file, but it is not uploaded.

HTML code is:

```
<form action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" style="float:left; background-image: url(design.png); ">
  <div class="fallback">
     <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
</form>
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated since I now tried everything and still no result.

response i get local:

```
tempFile C:\xampp\tmp\php89FF.tmp
file_name 4337681
imageName 4337681.jpg
targetPath  C:\xampp\htdocs\designer\pk\../uploads\
targetFile  C:\xampp\htdocs\designer\pk\../uploads\4337681.jpg
BCK../uploads/4337681.jpg
```

response i get on server:

```
tempFile /tmp/phpjs6s9x
file_name 5394604
imageName 5394604.jpg
targetPath  /var/www/designer/pk\..\uploads\
targetFile  /var/www/designer/pk\..\uploads\5394604.jpg
BCK../uploads/5394604.jpg
```

Comment: do you have php errors enabled? try error_reporting(E_ALL); at the beginning of your script.

Comment: i enabled it now, no error found, i get the post response path to image but image is not uploaded or created in the folder

Comment: Make sure the folder has write permissions set. @enigmaticus and if you're trying to upload more than one file, you will need to use square brackets `name="file[]"` to be treated as an array. Otherwise, it will only take one upload.

Comment: Also change this line `$storeFolder = '..\uploads';` to `$storeFolder = '../uploads/';`

Comment: please check the update for the responses

Comment: [`See my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22098166/) (tested working) @enigmaticus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and had to add a few things to make it work, which will most likely work for you as well.

`method="post"` was missing in:

```
<form action="action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" style="float:left; background-image: url(design.png); ">
  <div class="fallback">
     <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
</form>
```

which is required when uploading files.

Also, missing square brackets for `name="file"` which should read as `name="file[]"` - It didn't work for me till I added it, because of the `foreach` argument.

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error)
```

The brackets are required when using a `foreach` and multiple files, so that it's treated as an array.

Your form should now read as:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" style="float:left; background-image: url(design.png); ">
  <div class="fallback">
     <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
  </div>
</form>
```

I added `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">` since I didn't see it in your posted code.

You also could change `$storeFolder = '..\uploads';` to `$storeFolder = '../uploads';` with a `/` instead of `\` but that might not make a difference, yet on some systems it does; I've seen it happen before.

Comment: this is because that is made with javascript, i add automatically [] if there is option multiple enabled

Comment: I suggest you test it "as is" with my answer/form etc. then add in your JS after. Most likely it's your JS that is causing the problem. @enigmaticus I wouldn't post code if it didn't work. I test all my answers before submitting. Even with JS, `method="post"` is required.

Comment: You're trying on a hosted site? Have all files been uploaded, paths are correct etc. JS loaded etc? @enigmaticus

Comment: yes, everything, when i get the response from POST with javascript i make an alert() with the path to the image. But the image is not uploaded.

Comment: and the permissions i tried with 0777 and 0755 and still not working :S

Comment: And from what I can tell by what you posted `targetPath /var/www/designer/pk\..\uploads\` you're probably using something like `$storeFolder = '/var/www/designer/pk/';` @enigmaticus

Comment: no, i use uploads, that is from the dirname( __FILE__ ) while running it on the server

Comment: What versions of PHP is on your local machine and the one on the hosted site? @enigmaticus

Comment: hosted: <h1 class="p">PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8</h1>

local: <h1 class="p">PHP Version 5.3.8</h1>

Comment: I don't know, am baffled and I don't know anything about Ubuntu. I Google'd it, but didn't find much. Can you try `$storeFolder = '/var/www/designer/pk/uploads';` or wherever the uploads folder is on the server. @enigmaticus

Comment: Plus, have you tried it without the fancy stuff, just the exact code for the form and PHP in my answer, without anything added? @enigmaticus

Comment: ha ha ha ha it worked with this storeFolder, obviously DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR was making problems :D omfg :D i was working on this plugin 10 days 10 hours per day and i thought today when i put it on the server that i will get a nervous break down (this needs to be delivered to client till wednesday) :D thanks a lot, you saved me :)

Comment: Sometimes even a simple missing dot (or other small char.) will mess up your day. @enigmaticus

Answer (score 1):

try to change this line:

```
$storeFolder = '..\uploads';
```

to this:

```
$storeFolder = '..' . $ds .  'uploads';
```

Comment: still, try to `echo $targetFile` when it's built. Look if that really makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make create your target path folders if not created and consider not creating them if already exist. You need also to make sure that, the destination folder is writable. use "docroot" for referring to the root folder on your server. You can use something like this

```
        if($_FILES )
    {
        $user_id=$_GET['user_id'];
        $device_id=$_GET['device_id'];
        $backup_id=$_GET['backup_id'];
        $images_folder='images';
        $target_path=DOCROOT.$user_id.'\\'.$device_id.'\\'.$backup_id.'\\'.$images_folder.'\\';
        if ( ! is_dir($target_path) OR ! is_writable($target_path))
        {
            mkdir($target_path, 0777, TRUE);
        }
        $target_path = $target_path .$_FILES['uploadedfile']['size']. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
        {
            $image_path=$target_path;
            $image_size=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'];
            $image = ORM::factory('image');
            $image=$image->new_image($_GET['backup_id'],$image_path,$image_size,$_GET['mobile_path'],file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedthumb']['tmp_name']));
            echo "Server: Image: ".basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).", uploaded successfully";
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "Server: Error";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "no file attached";
    }
```